# nginx try_files: 404 when attempting to add extension and fall back to Passenger/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm struggling a bit with a proper `nginx` declaration.
What I'd like to do is fairly simple: for any request to `*.public.domain.com`, I'd like to look for a cached file, and if one is unavailable, send the request to Passenger/Rails to process.

Cached files, if they exist, have `.html` appended to prevent directory/file conflicts, so `/test` should look for `/test.html` and `/test/2` should look for `/test/2.html`.
Cached files are specific to subdomains, so `abc.public.domain.com` should look in the `/sites/abc` folder.

Here is the relevant nginx code:

```
    server {
      # listen/SSL stuff removed for brevity

      server_name *.public.domain.com;

      location ~ "^(.*)\.public\.domain\.com" {
        root /var/applications/app/current/sites/$1;
        try_files $request_uri.html $request_uri/index.html @passenger;
      }

      location @passenger {
          root /var/applications/app/current/public;
          passenger_enabled on;
          passenger_user www-data;
      }
    }
```

In my log files, I see that nginx is attempting to load files without the .html extension.  For example, I see this: `/var/applications/app/current/sites/abc/test" failed (2: No such file or directory)` but no attempt to load `test.html`.  So it seems the subdomain regex and the root declaration are working fine; adding the extension is not.

So that's problem 1.

Problem 2 is that, upon failing to find the file, nginx is not falling back to `@passenger;` it's throwing a 404 rather than allowing Rails to handle the request and serve the file itself.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?  I've read quite a bit about `nginx` configuration and can't figure out where the mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it looks like after much fiddling I've managed to get this working.  Here's the updated code:

```
server {
  # listen/SSL stuff removed for brevity

  server_name *.public.domain.com;

  #location ~ "^(.*)\.public\.domain\.com" {
  #  root /var/applications/app/current/sites/$1;
  #  try_files $request_uri.html $request_uri/index.html @passenger;
  #}

  if ($host ~ "^(.*)\.public\.domain\.com" ) { set $subdomain $1; }
  root /var/applications/app/current/sites/$subdomain/;
  try_files $request_uri.html $request_uri/index.html @passenger;

  location @passenger {
      root /var/applications/app/current/public;
      passenger_enabled on;
      passenger_user www-data;
  }
}
```

I've commented out the old code for easy reference in case this is useful to anybody else.  Two changes seem to have done the trick:

1. I added a trailing slash to `root`.  I didn't see this done in any of the (many) examples I read, but it seems to have been necessary here.  (That's also strange because before nginx was looking in the right place, minus the extension, so I'm not sure why it would make a difference, but I'm not going to look a gift horse in the mouth.)
2. I removed the location block.  I can't be certain what was going on, but it seems like nginx would try to load a file matching $request_uri before processing `try_files` in a location block, but outside that block it processed `try_files` before attempting to load non-existent files.

For the record, I'm reverse proxying to this server, which might have had something to do with my problems.  There was an nginx bug earlier version having to do with `request_uri` in `try_files` after parodying (check the change log if that's relevant to you) but they should have been fixed in the latest version, which I'm now running.

It's possible I'm making some very basic mistake here and I just lucked into a working version, but I figured I would document this in case it's ever useful to anyone else.